# Interest of "Existing Single Sign On" on Access Panel

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My question is about Azure Access Panel.

I tested the case "**Existing Single Sign On**" with Github application.

As a result, I don't have any king of SSO, but I just arrive on the Github's logon panel.

So I was asking me what is the interest of this option?

Answer (score 0):

As per https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appssoaccess-whatis/

> **Existing Single Sign-On** enables Azure AD to leverage any existing single sign-on that has been set up for the application, but enables these applications to be linked to the Office 365 or Azure AD access panel portals, and also enables additional reporting in Azure AD when the applications are launched there.

Basically, this option is meant for cases where the application is already set up for SSO and provides you with a url specific to your instance of the app, for example:

```
  https://mycompany.salesforce.com
```

You'd then pick "Existing SSO" and point it to this URL.

This is mostly meant as a convenience for users that access most of their applications through the access panel or the Office 365 app launcher. It doesn't actually do any SSO related setup itself.